# Redux fetch data from api

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am trying to fetch some data from an api using Redux. My code looks like this:

Action:

```js
// Import libraries
import axios from 'axios';

// Import types
import {
  GET_ALL_PICKS
} from './types';

export const getAllPicks = ({ token }) => {
  const getPicks = (dispatch) => {
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://myapi/',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data); // First log here returns data just fine
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ALL_PICKS,
        payload: response.data
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  };

  return getPicks;
};
```

Reducer:

```js
// Import types
import {
  GET_ALL_PICKS
} from '../actions/types';

// Set Initial State
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  allPicks: {},
  loading: false,
  error: ''
};

// Make pick reducers
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_ALL_PICKS:
      return { ...state, allPicks: action.payload }; // Logging action.payload here returns data just fine
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Component:

```js
// Import Libraries
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {
  getAllPicks
} from '../actions/picks';

// Make Component
class HomeScreen extends Component {
  // Fetch Data
  componentWillMount() {
    const { token } = this.props;

    this.props.getAllPicks({ token });
  }

  // Test response
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.allPicks); // This log returns empty object, why?!
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Test</Text>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ auth, picks }) => {
  const { token } = auth;
  const { allPicks } = picks;

  return {
    token,
    allPicks
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getAllPicks })(HomeScreen);
```

When I run the app I see the data in the action `console.log` and if I run a `console.log(action.payload)` in the reducer I see the data just fine but in component I see an empty array which suggests I'm not hooking up the data in my reducer correctly? Here's a screen shot of the logs:

[image]

I have also tried this in my reducer after some Googling:

```
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    allPicks: action.payload
  });
```

but again I got the same result. Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the component lifecycle and the API lifecycle.

In practice, what's happening is:

- componentWillMount
- getAllPicks
- componentDidMount (at which point, the API didn't return, the picks are empty)
- [... wait for the API to return]
- then the API returns with the data, but too late

What you need to do then is check for your "picks" state in the `render()` function, which will be updated each time your state changes (which happens when the API returns), thanks to the `connect()` function.

You can also check that the picks are updated properly using `componentWillUpdate`, not `componentDidMount` which again has nothing to do with the props being updated.